# Grafana dashboard panel is taking 5 to 8 seconds to load

Tags: performance, load, panel, grafana

I am using Grafana version 5.1.3 (commit: 087143285) ,InfluxDB shell version: 1.5.2 along with jmeter.

There are 13 panels. Panel is taking 5 to 8 seconds to load.
Below query is running for panel:(When I run the same query on db server it is running very fast )

SELECT mean(“startedThreads”) FROM “virtualUsers” WHERE time >= 1537865329564ms and time <= 1537867129564ms GROUP BY time(60s) fill(null);

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
execution_time: 157.341µs
planning_time: 626.44µs
total_time: 783.781µs
SELECT count(“responseTime”)/60 FROM “requestsRaw” WHERE time >= 1537865329564ms and time <= 1537867129564ms GROUP BY time(60s) fill(null)"
execution_time: 535.011µs
planning_time: 1.805892ms
total_time: 2.340903ms

Below is memory and cpu details.Influx db and Grafans are hosted on same server.

free -g
total used free shared buff/cache available
Mem: 15 3 11 0 1 12
Swap: 7 0 6

CPU(s): 2
On-line CPU(s) list: 0,1
Thread(s) per core: 1
Core(s) per socket: 2
Socket(s): 1

And as per my initial understanding Grafana minimum memory requirement is 249MB.So memory is not problem for Grafana.

Please let me if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

It is odd that the query runs fast while Grafana needs a long time. Panels should be diplayed as soon as Grafana gets a response.

Since rendering is done in the Browser AFAIK this could be the bottleneck. So if your Browser runs on a Raspberry Pi 1, please try using a different computer.

It is not clear if all Panels need a long time to load or if it is just one Panel that needs a long time. You should try to find out if the loading time is related to just one Panel.

Lastly consider that all queries are sent at the same time, so making just one query to the server from CLI may not be representative. You could try to spliting the Dashboard in multiple Dashboards to improve the loading time.